# Gulp folder compiling

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I am relatively new to gulp. I have one issue when I try to compile one directory with subfolders with their sass files.

Folder structure:

```
|_sass
   |__folder1
   |   |_file.sass
   |__folder2
   |   |_file.sass
   |__folder3
       |_file.sass
```

My simple gulp task to try the compilation

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return sass('sass/')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css');
}
```

This task above doesn't work with a folder but if I specify the file like in gulp task below, it works correctly.

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return sass('sass/folder1/file1.sass')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css');
}
```

I have checked the documentation of the [repository (gulp-ruby-sass)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass) and other topics in stackoverflow and the one solution that i have found is import all sass code into one file and compile it.

I have tried different paths: `./sass`, `sass`, `sass/` even the last syntax with `gulp.src(path/**/*.sass)` with `gulp-sass` repository as well.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Im using webstorm with gulpfile.js

Comment: The solutions you've found are correct. Create a main sass file and import all the files you want to use.

Comment: So if i want to separate my final css in two for differents parts of my application i need two gulp tasks? I think that it is not the way.

Comment: ohh so you want the output to be file1.css, file2.css etc?

Comment: Yes. I want diferent css. Now is a simple example but in my application i will need different final css. Maybe two or three.

Comment: Why are you prefixing the filenames with an underscore if you want them to compile to individual CSS files?

Comment: it Is not a underscore, is for draw the tree structure. The names are sass, folderN and file.sass

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Using `gulp-sass`, not `gulp-ruby-sass`, since `gulp-ruby-sass` does only support single files, as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass#important):

> gulp-ruby-sass doesn't support globs yet, only single files or directories. Just like Sass.

You should create a stream with valid glob arguments `gulp.src()` instead of just calling `sass()` directly and call it in a `pipe()`:

```
gulp.task('sass', function (){
  return gulp.src([
    'sass/folder1/file.sass',
    'sass/folder2/file.sass',
    'sass/folder3/file.sass'
  ])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

If the files you just want to import are named correctly (starting with an underscore), this should work as well:

```
gulp.task('sass', function (){
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

**Edit:** Fixed some code errors - SO needs a linter (;

Comment: Hi, i dont know what is the meaning of 'globs' but few words later it puts "or directories". I understood bad then. So i have tried with the procedure that you explain me with a common error, "Arguments to path.join must be strings". And this is the end for me, im still searching but i dont know what to do with this error.

Comment: Can you share your updated code that is not working?

Comment: I will try after work other time and i tell you. But is simple, with gulp-ruby-sass i can not compile directory, because is not possible according the naeramatrth7 post. And with gulp-sass sends me an error.